# Disabling ContentEditable tag in html?

Tags: html

For all I know, there is a tag `contenteditable` that allows something to be changed or edited. Let's say I'm doing this:

```
<head><h1>hi</h1></head><body contenteditable></body>
```

I make the body editable, but the elements in the head are also editable. How do I make it so that some elements **aren't** editable? Thanks!

Comment: um, why is there elements in your head???  Head is not meant for that. it is for meta data, styles, etc. Browser is probably fixing your issue and moves it into the body.

Comment: @epascarello oh ok

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have HTML elements in the head tag, so your browser converts it to this:

```
<head>
</head>
<body contenteditable>
  <h1>hi</h1>
</body>
```

Use an element other than body, which is the root element of any page. For example:

```
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <div contenteditable></div>
</body>
```

Example:

```css
#editable {
  border: solid 1px #f00;
}
```

```html
<head>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>hi</h1>
  <div id='editable' contenteditable></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Put contenteditable on the elements you want to make editable and don't put it on the body tag.